# At what moment during his flight did Yuri Gagarin eat?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, soviet-union, food, vostok-program

Gagarin's flight in space was rather short, but he still had time to eat [two tubes of meat and one of chocolate](https://culinarylore.com/food-history:what-was-the-first-food-eaten-in-space/). The [flight schedule on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vostok_1#Time_in_orbit) doesn't mention a meal. At what moment during his flight did Gagarin have time to eat?

Comment: Pretty short flight (and, full of action). If no data are found, it's prolly safe to assume he ate "on the go."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> В полете Ю. А. Гагарин пообедал. Из контейнера питания он достал щавелевое пюре с мясом, мясной паштет и шоколадный соус. После еды с помощью мундштука попил консервированной воды. Акт глотания не нарушался, и был сделан важный вывод о том, что в условиях космического полета можно принимать пищу и пить воду. Следует сказать, что большинство космонавтов с аппетитом ели в условиях невесомости. Особенно им нравился украинский борщ, мясной паштет, сосиски-малютки, виноградный сок и цукаты. Ю. А. Гагарину особенно по душе были печеночный паштет и абрикосовый сок.

During the flight, Yu. A. Gagarin had lunch. From the food container, he took out sorrel meat puree, meat pâté, and chocolate sauce. After eating, I drank canned water with a mouthpiece. The act of swallowing was not disturbed, and an important conclusion was made that in the conditions of space flight it is possible to eat and drink water. It should be said that most of the cosmonauts ate with appetite in zero gravity. They especially liked Ukrainian borscht, meat pâté, "baby"- sausages, grape juice and candied fruits. Yu. A. Gagarin especially liked liver pate and apricot juice.

http://epizodyspace.ru/bibl/znan/1985/11/11-perv-shagi.html
КОСМОНАВТИКА, АСТРОНОМИЯ 11/1985

И. И. Касьян, доктор медицинских наук
ПЕРВЫЕ ШАГИ В КОСМОС

COSMONAUTICS, ASTRONOMY  magazine; 11/1985
I. I. Kasyan, Doctor of Medical Sciences
FIRST STEPS IN SPACE

> Над Южной Америкой космонавт пообедал. Из контейнера питания он достал
> тубы со щавелевым пюре и мясом, мясной паштет и шоколадный соус. После
> еды через мундштук попил консервированной воды. Этим Юрий Гагарин
> впервые подтвердил предположение ученых, что с питанием человека на
> орбите не должно возникнуть серьезных проблем.

The cosmonaut dined over South America. From the food container, he took out tubes of sorrel puree and meat, meat pâté and chocolate sauce. After eating, Yuri Gagarin drank canned water through the mouthpiece. With this, Yuri Gagarin for the first time confirmed the assumption of scientists that there should be no serious problems with human nutrition in orbit.

page 364 (373 in pdf )
Первушин А. И. 108 минут, изменившие мир /
Pervushin A.I. 108 minutes that changed the world
http://epizodyspace.ru/bibl/pervushin/108/108-minut.pdf